# @nrwl/node:build: How to change output file name?

Tags: node.js, angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am working in a nx monorepo with Angular CLI and a Node backend. In angular.json, I use a custom webpack config to change the filename of the bundle. Calling `ng build app` (which invokes @nrwl/node:build) works fine and bundles the file with the specified name.

The thing is: Calling `ng serve app` gives the error `Cannot find module <path-to-outdir>/main.js`. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/36e1d407848163019ab9ffe5c4c71668c78ebccb/packages/node/src/builders/build/build.impl.ts#L80), it seems that the filename "main.js" is hardcoded!

How do I change the out filename in a way that @nrwl/node:execute is aware of that filename or is there any way to configure the build/execute to take a custom filename?

Thanks!

My angular.json looks like:

```
"service": {
  ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
      "options": {
        "webpackConfig": "apps/service/webpack.config.js",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/service",
        "filename": "my-main-filename.js", // Note: webpack.config.ts reads this
        "main": "apps/service/src/my-main-filename.ts",
        ...
        }
    },
    "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "service:build"
          },
    }
...
```

And the webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = (config, context) => {
  // Extract output path from context
  const {
    options: { outputPath, filename },
  } = context;

  config.output = {
    filename: filename,
    path: outputPath
  }
  return config;
};
```

The version of @nrwl/node is 9.2.1

Comment: I found a workaround that works for my setup. Moving the "outputPath" and "filename" entries to the production configuration section performs the rename only when calling `ng build --prod`. When  calling serve, the development options are taken and nrwl can cope.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specify anything on webpack.config. You can directly add in the project.json if you are using the "executor": "@nrwl/web:webpack" (https://nx.dev/packages/web/executors/webpack)

1. add @nrwl/workspace in package.json if not available (for me it comes by default while set up project)
2. in project.json/angular.json

```
"build": {
 "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
 "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
 "defaultConfiguration": "production",
 "options": {
   ...
   "outputPath": "dist/apps/service",
   "outputFileName": "my-main-filename.js",
   ...
 },
 "configurations": {
   "development": {
     "outputPath": "new path for development if needed"
   },
   "production": {}
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Adding `"outputFileName": "main.js"` to `project.json` (at the "build" target) fixed the error `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/.../dist/apps/backend/main.js'`.